# Is return keyword needed in non return functions?

Tags: python-3.x

I see some examples where `return` is the last statement in a function that doesn't return anything.  Is this needed in Python 3.x?

```
def myfunc():
  result = 1 + 1
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Return statements are not mandatory, if function exits without any return statement, `None` is returned.

Proof:

Quoting official docs, namely [Calls](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#calls) and [The return statement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):

About return:

> return leaves the current function call with the expression list (or None) as return value.

About calls:

> **A call always returns some value, possibly `None`**, unless it raises an exception. How this value is computed depends on the type of the callable object.
>
> If it is a user-defined function:
>
> The code block for the function is executed, passing it the argument list. The first thing the code block will do is bind the formal parameters to the arguments; this is described in section Function definitions. **When the code block executes a return statement, this specifies the return value of the function call.**

As we can conclude from docs - all functions implicitly returns `None`, unless explicit `return` statement is executed.

Comment: If you are returning None, is there any reason to have an empty return statement as the last line in a function?

Comment: @4thSpace: The `return` without an argument is the same as `return None`, and it is the same as not using the return statement at all. The only situation when you want to use it explicitly in such case is when you want to return from the function earlier than at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the last statement in a function is `return`, then it `return`s a value. If there is no `return` statement, it does not `return` anything.

Comment: You are incorrect.  If return is the last statement and isn't returning anything, then nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, "No".  For a function that mutates the input or causes a side-effect, `return` or `return None` should be omitted, unless needed for early exit, in which case I would use `return`.  However, I might use `return None` here:

```
def pos(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x
    else:
        return None
```

This could be condensed to this:

```
def pos(x):
    return x if x > 0 else None
```